# Connection pool in .net

Tags: .net, sql

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim iCount As Integer = 1
        Try
            Do
                Dim sqlConn As New  _
                SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;trusted_Connection=yes;initial catalog = MyDatabase;max pool size =100;")
                sqlConn.Open()
                Trace.WriteLine("opening connection " & CStr(iCount))
                'sqlConn.Close()
                'Trace.WriteLine("closing connection " & CStr(iCount))
                'sqlConn.Dispose()
                'Trace.WriteLine("disposing connection " & CStr(iCount))
                iCount = iCount + 1
            Loop Until iCount > 20000
        Catch ex As Exception
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

If I execute this code, this test app opens 115 connections to the database before it throws `The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool` exception. But there are only 100 connection in app pool. How is it possible?

Comment: He-he. You are right! I added them to List and I got an exception after the 100th connection. I'm not sure why I didn't saw it :). Could you copy-paste your comment as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: I have same doubt and wanted to know how you solved it... Its urgent..? @Egor4eg

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar: The problem is used connections were not disposed

Comment: does that mean we have to use sqlConn.close() ??

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar: you can use sqlConn.close(). But a better decision is 'using' block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess: since you're not holding references to the open connection objects maybe the first 15 are getting disposed and reused? Do you still get 115 if you push the connections onto a `List<>`?